# Fido U2F Public keys in registration response

Tags: authentication, certificates

What is the deference between the two public keys:

1. user public key (2nd element in Token response)
2. user public key inside signature

in U2F Token response for registration ?

[image: Token Response]

Comment: The same question for the key handle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same. Note that `signature` doesn't contain the data shown in grey - rather, it's a *signature* of that data.